# Problems with Chrome Speech Input Events

Tags: google-chrome, speech

I'm trying to use the Chrome speech input control. Basic operation is no problem, but I cannot get an event to fire after some speech is entered. Probably something stupid, but I can't see it.

Here's the html:

```
<input type="text" speech="speech" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"
           x-webkit-grammar="builtin:translate" id="inbNote"/>
```

I tried adding inline event handlers, to no avail. Then I tried a jQuery bind:

```
$('#inbNote').bind("onwebkitspeechchange", function(){alert($('#inbNote').val())});
```

I also tried "onspeechchange" as the event name. Neither does anything, as far as I can tell.

Also, everytime I click the microphone the little "speak now" bubble pops up. When I stop speaking, the contents of the bubble disappear, but the bubble itself remains displayed and on top. It will not close until I close Chrome completely. If I enter multiple speech inputs, I get multiple bubbles. Do I have some Chrome config problem? I'm using 18.0.1025.1 dev-m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `'webkitspeechchange'` not `'onwebkitspeechchange'`:

So, it would be:

```
$('#inbNote').bind("webkitspeechchange", function(){alert($('#inbNote').val())});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, the problem is not on your side.

The same happens on www.google.com, must be a bug in Chrome.